# Remove vertical space between two consecutive multline environments

Tags: multline

How can I remove the additional vertical space between two multline environments? In fact, I have a list of two-line-equations and I want the second line aligned to the right. So I write:

```
\begin{multline*}
x =  1 +  2 \\ + 3 +4
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
y =  a + b \\ + c + d
\end{multline*}
```

However, there is too much vertical space between the two equations. 
I tried different solutions using aligned, gathered, ... but I still can not get the second line aligned to the right. Some time ago I defined the macro

```
\newcommand{\SplitEq}[1][0cm]{\hfill\strut\\[#1]\strut\hfill}
```

which works as I would like it to work but just in inline math so that I have to add line breaks and vertical spaces manually:

```
\\[1ex] $ x =  1 +  2 \SplitEq + 3 +4 $ \\
$y =  a + b  \SplitEq + c + d $ \\[1ex]
```

Does anybody know any solution to this problem? I am interested in some "automatic" solutions, i.e. not requiring to specify e.g. \phantom{x=1+2}, if possible. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  `mathtools` has a `multlined` environment, so two of them could be included within a single `gather*` environment.  that might actually need a little extra space added between them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are these examples representative?  I don't understand what you're trying to achieve  exactly.

Comment: These are just examples, my equations are much longer. I would like to have a list of equations such that every odd equation is aligned to the left and every even to the right. The multlined environment sounds like what I want, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Just after I posted my answer, I noticed that you'd written a comment with the exact same solution suggestions. If you want to post your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to delete my answer.

Comment: @Mico -- you've got good examples, so keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is is close to what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}

 \begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
   & x = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10\\
 & & & & & \mathllap{{} + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17 + 18 + 19 + 20} \\
  & y = a + b + c + d + e + f + g +h \\
  & & & & & \mathllap{{} + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + h^2}
\end{flalign*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the result looks like what I want, thank you! However, I need some time to understand how this works...

Comment: Doesn't it work just with & & instead of & & & & & and without {} ?

Comment: It's quite simple: `flalign*` has three columns, flushleft , middle and flushright, each with its own alignment point. There's nothing in the middle column, as you can see, and the  supplementary trick is the use `\mathllap` from `mathtools`, which places its maths  flushright as though it had 0 width, in case the left and right parts vertically overlap.

Comment: @user32817: You're right, it works  with onlythree `&` (the number of them for n columns has to be 2n -1), but I'm not sure it works for shorter lines. As  to the  `{}+`, it  is to make `+` a binary operator , not a unary one, at the beginning of a line: they use a different spacing.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use two `multlined` environments inside a `gather*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'multlined' environment
\setlength\textwidth{6cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent
proposed form
\hrule
\begin{gather*}
\begin{multlined}
x =  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +6 \\ +7+8+9+10+11+12
\end{multlined}\\
\begin{multlined}
y =  a + b + c + d + e + f + g\\ +h+i+j+k+m+n+o
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}
\hrule

\bigskip\bigskip

\noindent
OP's original form:
\hrule
\begin{multline*}
x =  1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +6 \\ +7+8+9+10+11+12
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
y =  a + b + c + d + e + f + g\\ +h+i+j+k+m+n+o
\end{multline*}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to have the second case without the vertical space in the middle. My equations are namely longer and I find it better when the second equation is aligned to the right.

Comment: @user32817 - Having longer equations is not a problem for the `multlined` environments. I've modified the code to feature "longer" equations.